# Sort by month in Power BI. etc: Jan, Feb, March

Tags: windows-7-x64, powerbi

I want to ask how can I sort my chart by month (etc: Jan, Feb, Marc, Apr, ...) using Power BI?

I had try to put this:
**CalendarInv = CALENDAR ('KPI', 'KPI[Month]'), today())**

but it give me a pop up error:
"**The function MINX takes an argument that evaluates to numbers or dates and cannot work with values of type String**."

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I had try to put this: CalendarInv = CALENDAR ('KPI', 'KPI[Month]'), today())

Sorry for my mistake. The right one is:
Calendar = CALENDAR (MINX( 'KPI', 'KPI[Month]'), today())

Comment: Your `KPI[Month]` seems to be of string type, try changing its column type appropriately. Possibly change your import query to have it `int` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any repro or dummy data, or given any context to the formulas you posted, so I'm going to focus on the main question: how to sort by month.

**First up: make sure your source column is of type Date!** If it is a string, do a conversion in the query, model, or a new derived column, and work from there.

I'm assuming that you fixed that, and that you have something similar to this dummy data:

```
InvoiceDate;Value
2017-09-01;200
2017-09-16;300
2017-10-01;250
2017-11-01;230
2017-09-25;150
```

Now, there are several derived columns I suggest for easy month-based sorting:

1. `MonthNr = MONTH([InvoiceDate])`
2. `MonthNrWithName = FORMAT([InvoiceDate]; "MM (mmm)")`
3. `YearMonth1 = YEAR([InvoiceDate]) & "-" & IF(MONTH([InvoiceDate])<10;"0";"") & MONTH([InvoiceDate])`
4. `YearMonth2 = FORMAT([InvoiceDate]; "yyyy-MM")`

Here's what they look like in graphs:

[image: graphs of dataset]

I personally prefer option 4, usually.